# How do I modify an AWS Step function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

From the AWS console it seems like AWS Step functions are immutable. Is there a way to modify it ? If not how does the version control work ? Do I have to create a new State machine every time I have to make incremental changes to the state machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=244167) forum entry, there is no way *yet* to modify an existing state machine. You need to create a new one every time.

Comment: But, as stated in [Can't Edit a State Machine in Step Functions](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=244167) in the AWS forums, it is planned

Comment: This is no longer correct, you can now edit Step Functions

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you can edit state mashine. Buttton "Edit state machine" in right upper corner

Answer (score 0):

These days, I have been using CloudFormation w/ `boto3` . Going to just write it out here, because I had been a bit intimidated by CloudFormation in the past, but with an end to end example maybe it is more approachable.

`step_function_stack.yaml`

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: >-
  A description of the State Machine goes here. 
Resources:
  MyStateMachineName:
    Type: AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine
    Properties:
      RoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::{{aws_account_id}}:role/service-role/StepFunctions-MyStepFunctionRole"

      StateMachineName: "MyStateMachineName"
      StateMachineType: "EXPRESS"

      DefinitionString:
        Fn::Sub: |
          {{full_json_definition}}
```

`manage_step_functions.py`

```py
import boto3
import os
import time
from jinja2 import Environment


def do_render(full_json_definition):
    with open('step_function_stack.yaml') as fd:
        template = fd.read()
    yaml = Environment().from_string(template).render(
            full_json_definition=full_json_definition,
            aws_account_id=os.getenv('AWS_ACCOUNT_ID')) 
    return yaml


def update_step_function(stack_name, full_json_definition,):
    yaml = do_render(full_json_definition)
    client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
    response = client.update_stack(
        StackName=stack_name,
        TemplateBody=yaml,
        Capabilities=[
            'CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND',
        ])
    return response


def create_step_function(stack_name, full_json_definition,):
    yaml = do_render(full_json_definition)
    client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
    response = client.update_stack(
        StackName=stack_name,
        TemplateBody=yaml,
        Capabilities=[
            'CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND',
        ])
    return response
    

  def get_lambdas_stack_latest_events(stack_name):
      # Get the first 100 most recent events.
      client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
      return client.describe_stack_events(
          StackName=stack_name)


  def wait_on_update(stack_name):
      events = None
      while events is None or events['StackEvents'][0]['ResourceStatus'] not in ['UPDATE_COMPLETE',
              'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE', 'DELETE_COMPLETE', 'CREATE_COMPLETE']:

          print(events['StackEvents'][0]['ResourceStatus'] if events else ...)
          events = get_lambdas_stack_latest_events(stack_name)
          time.sleep(1)

      return events
```

`step_function_definition.json`

```json
{
  "Comment": "This is a Hello World State Machine from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/getting-started.html#create-state-machine",
  "StartAt": "Hello",
  "States": {
    "Hello": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": "Hello",
      "Next": "World"
    },
    "World": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": "World",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Create a step function

```py
# From a python shell for example
# First just set any privileged variables through environmental variables so they are not checked into code
# export AWS_ACCOUNT_ID=999999999

# edit step_function_definition.json then read it
with open('step_function_definition.json') as fd:
    step_function_definition = fd.read()
    
import manage_step_functions as msf
stack_name = 'MyGloriousStepFuncStack'
msf.create_step_function(stack_name, step_function_definition)
```

If you are ready to update your State Machine, you can edit `step_function_definition.json` or you might create a new file for reference, `step_function_definition-2021-01-29.json`. (Because at time of this writing Step Functions dont have versions like Lambda for instance).

```py
import manage_step_functions as msf
stack_name = 'MyGloriousStepFuncStack'
with open('step_function_definition-2021-01-29.json') as fd:
    step_function_definition = fd.read()

msf.update_step_function(stack_name, step_function_definition)
```